# How to make script which checks if a particular site is opened in any tabs of chrome(Android) and replaced it with another

Tags: android, web, automation, bots

My mobile will not be connected to windows etc, thus I cannot get that thing done through appium. Is there any other way to accomplish same. The time should be in seconds.All this be happening in background.
I am

My mobile will not be connected to windows etc, thus I cannot get that thing done through appium. Is there any other way to accomplish same. The time should be in seconds.All this be happening in background
Is something like that possible